# jQuery не удается отменить отправку формы

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit

На пустой [странице](http://1dl2xd9b.plp7.ru) есть форма. Моя задача - выполнить свой код вместо отправки этой формы.

Саму страницу редактировать не могу, так как это онлайн-конструктор, но могу добавлять свой код.

Никак не удается отменить отправку, хотя `submit` перехватываю. `e.preventDefault()` и `return false` не помогают.

Например такой код отправку перехватывает, но форма все равно отправляется.

```
<script>

$(".step1").submit ( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Перехват submit!');
    return false;
});

</script>
```

Не могу понять в чем причина.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cont">
    <div class="node node7 widget widget-form step1" outline="2">
      <div class="wrapper1">
        <div class="wrapper2">
          <div class="macros-form">
            <div class="outer" style="max-width: 350px;">
              <div class="inner">
                <div class="vertical none size-big">
                  <div class="head">
                    <div class="textable">
                      <p><strong>Шаг 1/2</strong></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="body">
                    <div class="cont"></div>
                    <form class="form text-in" data-form="{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Расчет&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;order&quot;,&quot;privacy&quot;:&quot;none&quot;,&quot;privacy_checkbox&quot;:&quot;Даю согласие на <обработку персональных данных>&quot;,&quot;after&quot;:&quot;msg&quot;,&quot;msg&quot;:&quot;Спасибо!\nВаша заявка отправлена.\nВ ближайшее время мы с Вами свяжемся!&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;addhtml&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;js&quot;:&quot;alert(\&quot;Этот код выполняется после успешного отправления заявки.\&quot;);&quot;,&quot;integrations&quot;:[]}"
                      data-fields="[{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Имя&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;name&quot;,&quot;required&quot;:true,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;&quot;},{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Телефон&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;phone&quot;,&quot;required&quot;:true,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;&quot;}]">
                      <div class="fields">
                        <div class="field" data-type="name">
                          <div class="input"><input class="form-control text" type="text" data-placeholder="true" value="Имя *" style="border-radius: 1px;"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field" data-type="phone">
                          <div class="input"><input class="form-control text" type="text" data-placeholder="true" value="Телефон *" style="border-radius: 1px;"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="macros-button">
                        <div class="btn-out full xs-none">
                          <div class="btn-inner"><button class="btn font-text submit" id="uid5" data-ym_goal="" data-ga_category="" data-ga_action=""><span class="text">Следующий шаг</span><input type="submit"></button></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                    <div class="cont"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: добавляйте html в вопрос

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужно подсоединить обработчик события `submit` к элементу формы, который находится внутри `.step1`:

```
$(".step1 form").submit ( function(e) {
  ...
});
```

```js
$(".step1").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Перехват submit!');
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="cont">
    <div class="node node7 widget widget-form step1" outline="2">
      <div class="wrapper1">
        <div class="wrapper2">
          <div class="macros-form">
            <div class="outer" style="max-width: 350px;">
              <div class="inner">
                <div class="vertical none size-big">
                  <div class="head">
                    <div class="textable">
                      <p><strong>Шаг 1/2</strong></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="body">
                    <div class="cont"></div>
                    <form class="form text-in" data-form="{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Расчет&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;order&quot;,&quot;privacy&quot;:&quot;none&quot;,&quot;privacy_checkbox&quot;:&quot;Даю согласие на <обработку персональных данных>&quot;,&quot;after&quot;:&quot;msg&quot;,&quot;msg&quot;:&quot;Спасибо!\nВаша заявка отправлена.\nВ ближайшее время мы с Вами свяжемся!&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;addhtml&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;js&quot;:&quot;alert(\&quot;Этот код выполняется после успешного отправления заявки.\&quot;);&quot;,&quot;integrations&quot;:[]}"
                      data-fields="[{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Имя&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;name&quot;,&quot;required&quot;:true,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;&quot;},{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;Телефон&quot;,&quot;type&quot;:&quot;phone&quot;,&quot;required&quot;:true,&quot;id&quot;:&quot;&quot;}]">
                      <div class="fields">
                        <div class="field" data-type="name">
                          <div class="input"><input class="form-control text" type="text" data-placeholder="true" value="Имя *" style="border-radius: 1px;"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field" data-type="phone">
                          <div class="input"><input class="form-control text" type="text" data-placeholder="true" value="Телефон *" style="border-radius: 1px;"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="macros-button">
                        <div class="btn-out full xs-none">
                          <div class="btn-inner"><button class="btn font-text submit" id="uid5" data-ym_goal="" data-ga_category="" data-ga_action=""><span class="text">Следующий шаг</span><input type="submit"></button></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                    <div class="cont"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Даже Ваш код работает - смотрите пример. При чем любого из двух методов остановки сабмита (`e.preventDefault();` или `return false;`) - достаточно. В Вашем коде есть еще что-то, чего Вы не показали, а я не могу догадаться, так как израсходовал большую часть сегодняшнего запаса телепатии на [Функция load выполняется два раза подряд](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/794745).

Comment: К сожалению, отправка все равно идет.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что этот код должен работать, но ведь не работает, как и написал. Потому и ищу причину, которая судя по всему в js коде того онлайн-конструктора. Приложил бы скрипты от него, но не выходит из за лимита количества символов. А взять только "нужную" часть не могу, так как не понимаю какая нужна... В этом ведь и загвоздка.

Comment: Лично Вам, @Igor, я на самом деле искренне благодарен за попытку помочь, спасибо (без сарказма и иронии).