# Функция load выполняется два раза подряд

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть набор функций, какие должны выполнится после загрузки контента, функцией load. Так вот все что происходит до load вызывается один раз, все что должно сработать после load, вызывается два раза. Я уже проверил все элементы, все классы, везде один экземпляр. Есть хоть какие-то варианты обойти это?

```
    function modalPagesOptions(el_page) {
        // el_page.data('modal-id') - id модального окна
        // $('.modal[data-id]') - html код модального окна с разными id
        if (el_page.data('modal-id') !== undefined && $('.modal[data-id]').exists()) {
            // Получаю окно, какое мне необходимо
            curr_modal = $('.modal[data-id=' + el_page.data('modal-id') + ']');
        } else {
            // Получаю окно, какое есть на странице
            curr_modal = $('.modal[data-id]');
        }

        // Если окно не отображено, отображаю его
        if (!curr_modal.data('bs.modal').isShown) curr_modal.modal('show');

        // ТУТ ВСЕ ЕЩЕ ОДИН ВЫЗОВ

        // el_page.data('page') - адрес страницы
        curr_modal.find('.modal-content').load(el_page.data('page'), function () {

            // ТУТ УЖЕ ДВА ВЫЗОВА. 
            // И ВТОРОЙ ВЫЗОВ ПРОИСХОДИТ СРАЗУ ЖЕ ПОСЛЕ ТОГО КАК ОТРАБОТАЮТ ВСЕ ФУНКЦИИ 

            func1();
            func2();
            func3();
            func4();

            modal_preloader.fadeOut(0);
            curr_modal.find('.modal-content').fadeIn(400);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Вас больше одного `'.modal-content'` внутри выборки `curr_modal`.

Comment: Я в шоке, проверил еще раз. Вы правы, спасибо. Оказывается нужно было проверить кол-во экземпляров до функции load, а я проверял все после load.

Comment: @VladPanchenko На здоровье. Меня иногда посещает бизнес-идея - выступать с показательными сеансами "телепатии/угадывания кода на расстоянии". Успехов!